# How can I see the image?

Tags: animation, image

I'm trying to create a flag animation, when I'm adding an image this pink color appear. How do I make the image show? I'm new to blender.

[image]

Comment: pink means that the image is missing, so there's a problem here, maybe reopen the image in your Image Texture node?

Comment: Thank you, I tried a different image and it worked with another image!

Comment: Some of my images are showing and some are not is there a reason for this?

Comment: we lack informations here, I can't tell  ;)

Comment: From your screen ... Texture node doesnt display "Color Space" ... there should be some :) Unsupported file format? Unsupported character in file name or directory path? If you open side panel (N) in shader editor with Texture node selected you can see under properties if given path to image can be loaded.